# How can you force Ajax content to reload when a user presses the back button on a Browser?

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching, browser-cache

I have a product listing page that lists the products, the pagination and some filters using Ajax.

That is all fine, but I find when a user clicks into a product and then uses the back button to go back to the product listing page the Ajax content doesn't load properly. If I refresh the page it is fine.

I have already added a dynamic back button on the product page that goes back and loads properly, but I need to try and capture when a user hits the back button.

I tried the following:

- Make the cache control must-revalidate, so when the Browser goes back the page is refreshed.
- Catch the event of the user clicking back on the product page and redirect them using the link that is used by the back button.

Unfortunately, none of these have worked for me, so I was wondering if anyone had any ideas.

Comment: Maybe [HTML PushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history/) will give you some ideas? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pushstate Might also give some good reads.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, to force the browser to refresh the page when back browser button was cliked, it works for me:

```
//disable ajax cache it solves that the Ajax content doesn't load properly when back button is clicked
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
//force reload page on back browser button
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    if(event && event.state) {
        location.reload()
    }
}
```